# Embedded flash player disappears in a pixelated manner

Tags: flash

It's difficult to describe the problem, but if you visit http://kinetichifi.com/listenpop.php it's really clear. It's like when you have one of those residual explorer windows open in Windows that you can "erase" by dragging another window over it. I'd really appreciate any suggestions on why this might be.

Comment: I actually don't see what you're talking about, but I do see this error in the debug player TypeError: Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert flash.events::Event@3dc8c8a9 to OpenEvent.
This probably means you're loading a swf into a different ApplicationDomain that has a conflicting definition of the Class. This is often what the string after the @ is somehow getting at (although, since the Class names are different, maybe not).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what the root cause of this problem was, but it turns out that it didn't happen in any other browsers (I was using Firefox 13.0.2). I ended up downloading an earlier version of flash (10.something from 11.something) and it works now.